# java jar accept multiple arguments on runtime

Tags: java, jar

I have a java jar that need to accept about 3 arguments but I want to pass them as a Q&A type like the following:
1st step run java jar

```
java -jar myTest.java
```

2nd step ask questions and wait for answers:

```
Hi, how old are you?
```

I type my answer that accepts it and then ask the 2nd question:

```
nice! what is your name?
```

type my second answer and the get a third question and so on. how do I achieve this? I know that I can pass arguments to main but what I found is that I have to pass them all when I first run the jar not like what I'm looking for. 
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Scanner?? System.in ??

Comment: Surely you have written some code you can share with us.

Comment: Check this post: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-standard-input-in-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to interact with an application depends of the logic in the application itself...

if you need to give parameters that the application needs from the start point then you give those as soon as you run the application

```
java -jar myTest.java
```

all those parameters are getting passed to the string[] parameter in the public static void main method...

in your case, (and if I got the question right) you will need more information from the user, and this is given at runtime... so you need another way to do that like Scanner class allowing you to read input from the terminal too...

Use the Scanner class and read the user input from the console..

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hi, " + input + ", where are you from");
    input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ohh, " + input + " is  nice place I guess!");
    System.out.println("and how old are you??");
         ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mixing up concepts.

*Command line* arguments are those strings that you see as String[] args parameter to your main method!

But you want the user to provide "more" input to your application, the typical way is to read them from "stdin" (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html) to learn how to do that).

Those two are fundamentally different things; and you should first clarify which one you really intend to use (given your example ... probably the "stdin" option).

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the Java IO tutorial here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html